# Django calls wrong function on given url

Tags: python, django

django calls the "listing" function even though I told it to use the "watchlist" function when handling the request which arises when going to the .../watchlist url. I can't find the problem.
Here is the error:

```
  File "/home/simon/Dokumente/cs50WebProgramming/commerce/auctions/views.py", line 103, in listing
    listing_obj = AuctionListing.objects.get(id=int(listing_id))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'watchlist'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create", views.create_listing, name="create"),
    path("after_create", views.after_create, name="after_create"),
    path("<str:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
    path("<str:listing_id>/bid", views.after_bid, name="after_bid"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist")
]
```

**views.py**

```
def listing(request, listing_id):
    listing_obj = AuctionListing.objects.get(id=int(listing_id))

    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "listing": listing_obj
    })

def watchlist(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the order of your URL paths. You have `<str:listing_id>` before `watchlist` which leads to any string path to be matched with `<str:listing_id>`. Simply re-order your paths and you should be fine:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create", views.create_listing, name="create"),
    path("after_create", views.after_create, name="after_create"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist")
    path("<str:listing_id>/bid", views.after_bid, name="after_bid"),
    path("<str:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
]
```

Comment: Also, check Willem Van Onsem's answer which he point's out some useful changes/optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `<str:listing_id>` matches any string, including `watchlist`, and since `watchlist` is defined first, it will fire the `listing` view. You can change the order, but you can alo restrict the path to only accept ints:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('create/', views.create_listing, name='create'),
    path('after_create/', views.after_create, name='after_create'),
    path('watchlist/', views.watchlist, name='watchlist'),
    path('<int:listing_id>/', views.listing, name='listing'),
    path('<int:listing_id>/bid/', views.after_bid, name='after_bid')
]
```

By using `<int:…>`, it will only fire for sequences of digits, furthermore using `int` is no longer necessary, since the value is automatically converted to an `int`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def listing(request, listing_id):
    listing_obj = get_object_or_404(AuctionListing, id=listing_id)

    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "listing": listing_obj
    })
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.